# TypeError: s.replace is not a function when removeConstraint

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm building an app with sequelize 5.5.0. I created some models; like **courses** and **coursecategory** are some tables in DB. I need add the **foreing key** **courseCategory** to **course** table... 
(one category has many courses)
But when i create the *migration* and add *Constraint* with *addConstraint()* all's right but when revert this show the error

I understand that if i create the constraint in the beggin i could resolve that but in my case i'll migrate one proyect and there are a lot records in existent Database. So for example in future case if i wish to create a constraint and i create my migration i cannot revert that

Afther that i have the **course model** like..

```
const Course = sequelize.define('Course', {
   //attributes
        courseId:{
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull : false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        category:{
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull:false,
            defaultValue: 1
        }
      });
```

my **coursecategory model**

```
    const Coursecategory = sequelize.define('Coursecategory', {
        //atributes
        coursecategoryId:{
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull : false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        name:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        order:{
            type: DataTypes.SMALLINT.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull:false,
            defaultValue: 0
        }
      }, {});
```

and my **constraint migration** it's here...

```
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

          return  await  queryInterface.addConstraint('courses', ['category'], {
                type: 'foreign key',
                name: 'courses_category_coursecategories_fk',
                references: {
                  table: 'coursecategories',
                  field: 'coursecategoryId',
                },
                defaultValue: 0,
                allowNull: true,
                onDelete: 'no action',
                onUpdate: 'no action',
              })
          },

      down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

             return await queryInterface.removeConstraint('courses', ['courses_category_coursecategories_fk'],{})

          }
```

I expect the migration run fine. I review the *INFORMATION_SCHEMA* table and my Key (courses_category_coursecategories_fk) is there. But somethings happen and i not receive more logg that..

```
ERROR: s.replace is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeConstraint` accepts a string as a second argument, not an array, see the [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-removeConstraint). Should work like this:

```
return await queryInterface.removeConstraint('courses','courses_category_coursecategories_fk')
```